# NVL function in oracle is not returning any records

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to fetch the records in Oracle database with nvl function but it return no records. Currently there are no null value in USER_ID column.

Queries:

Query 1 :`Select * from "Schemaname"."tablename" where nvl("USER_ID",'aaa') in('TestUser')`

Query 2 : `Select * from "schemaname"."tablename" where USER_ID in('TestUser')`

Query 1 which is using the NVL function doesn't return any record but query 2 returns a record. Can anyone help to find why query 1 is not returning a record

Comment: Use [coalsece](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617) as a habit.. Better performance

Comment: Is this a test / trick question?  Query 1 selects from a different table than query 2.  Query 1 is selecting from table "tablename" in the "Schemaname" schema, which is different from "tablename" in the "schemaname" schema, since the double quotes make the identifiers case-sensitive.  Apart from that, I see no problem with the `NVL` part of query 1 that would cause it to exclude the rows that would b returned by query 2.  Try posting your actual queries.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Am I needing more coffee here?  Why would the removing the double quotes in query 1 fix this?

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak :) well, I just drank coffee and can see that you're right, both are the same ....

Answer (score 1):

> NVL lets you replace null (returned as a blank) with a string in the results of a query. If expr1 is null, then NVL returns expr2. If expr1 is not null, then NVL returns expr1.

**UPD**

@Gordon Linoff is totally right that my first suggestion was wrong - double quotation is only a delimitation of DB entities. Buuut - it costs more then most people think. By default Oracle is a case-insentive DBMS, but when you start use double quotes everything is changing. The only suspicious difference between queries is a uppercased "S" in the "Schemaname" of the first query.

Actually we can create any number of similar objects, e.g script

```
create table "abc_001" (
       user_id varchar2(16)
);

create table "abC_001" (
       user_id varchar2(16)
);

create table "AbC_001" (
       user_id varchar2(16)
);
```

Will be done successfully, and it touches all the objects of the DBMS, so now I almost sure that the problem in this letter. These queries are syntactically correct, but the are do request to different schemas.

So I'm removing incorrect part of my first answer.

Comment: In Oracle, double quotes delimit identifiers not constants, so I don't understand your answer.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff my bad. You are rigth! I'll stay the answer for a while my little investigation. If I don't succeed i'll remove the answer, otherwise i'll update it.
Thanks for a point out!)

Comment: @Gordon Linoff as i promised i've updated the answer)

Comment: @YuriyTsarkov :  No,  queries was executed on same schema.  I tried  nvl function with "Schemaname"."tablename" and "schemaname"."tablename" but no record returned

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your logic, as the following queries demonstrate:

> ```
> select * from dual
> ```
>
> ```
> | DUMMY |
> | :---- |
> | X     |
> ```

> ```
> select * from dual where dummy in ('X')
> ```
>
> ```
> | DUMMY |
> | :---- |
> | X     |
> ```

> ```
> select * from dual where nvl(dummy, 'Y') in ('X')
> ```
>
> ```
> | DUMMY |
> | :---- |
> | X     |
> ```

> ```
> select * from dual where nvl(null, dummy) in ('X')
> ```
>
> ```
> | DUMMY |
> | :---- |
> | X     |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ff585ce04399cb886d9f8e51cafa6539)*

If you can post a screenshot or better a screen recording of your oracle queries replicating the problem we might think be able to see something else that can help or explain

There isn’t much point writing your first query that way though - null values won’t match the value inside the IN, and neither will the 'aaa' ever match ‘testuser’ so the effect is the same whether you use nvl like this or not